# Read and convert row in text file into list of string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file `data.txt` that contains 2 rows of text.

```
first_row_1    first_row_2    first_row_3
second_row_1    second_row_2    second_row_3
```

I would like to read the second row of the text file and convert the contents into a list of string in python. The list should look like this;

`txt_list_str=['second_row_1','second_row_2','second_row_3']`

Here is my attempted code;

```
import csv
with open('data.txt', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    row1 = next(reader)
    row2 = next(reader)

my_list = row2.split("  ")
```

I got the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

I am using python v3.

EDIT: Thanks for all the answers. I am sure all of them works. But can someone tell me what is wrong with my own attempted code? Thanks.

Comment: Coming. Please hold on. Will take me some time.

Comment: @DavidG, I just edited the question and put in my attempt. Oh.. I missed your answer while I was working on mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is you are trying to use `split` on a list, but it is meant to be used on a string. Therefore in your example you would use `row2[0]` to access the first element of the list.

```
my_list = row2[0].split("    ")
```

Alternatively, if you have access to the `numpy` library you can use [loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

```
import numpy as np

f = np.loadtxt("data.txt", dtype=str, skiprows=1)

print (f)
# ['second_row_1' 'second_row_2' 'second_row_3']
```

The result of this is an array as opposed to a list. You could simply cast the array to a list if you require a list

```
print (list(f))
#['second_row_1', 'second_row_2', 'second_row_3']
```

Comment: Yep, it was an array rather than a list. I have edited the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help! Verified to be the correct answer. I will check out numpy. Looks short and elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Use **read** file method to open file.

**E.g.**

```
>>> fp = open('temp.txt')
```

Use file inbuilt generator to iterate lines by **next** method, and ignore first line.

```
>>> next(fp)
'first_row_1    first_row_2    first_row_3)\n'
```

Get second line in any variable.

```
>>> second_line = next(fp)
>>> second_line
'second_row_1    second_row_2    second_row_3'
```

Use **Split** string method to get items in list. split method take one or zero argument. if not given they split use white space for split.

```
>>> second_line.split()
['second_row_1', 'second_row_2', 'second_row_3']
```

And finally close the file.

```
fp.close()
```

---

Note: There are number of way to get respective output.
But you should attempt first as DavidG said in comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is close to my attempted code. Would you mind pointing out what is wrong with my attempted code in the question?

Comment: DavidG has answered my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    next(f)    # skipping first line; will work without this too
    for line in f:
        txt_list_str = line.split()
print(txt_list_str)
```

Output

```
['second_row_1', 'second_row_2', 'second_row_3']
```